# Why won't my div sit on top of my image in ie7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm aware of the ie7 z-index bug yet I still can't get a div to sit on top of an image in ie. This is the current code I have:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="copy">...</div>
    <div id="toggle-view"></div>
    <img id="view" src="/..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the styling:

```
#wrapper { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto 0 auto; background: #fff; }
#content { width: 960px; height: 555px; position: relative; z-index: 20; }
#toggle-view { display: block; width: 150px; height: 25px; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 12px; right: 10px; z-index: 10; }
#view { width: 722px; height: 555px; position: relative; z-index: 1; }
```

This works fine in Chrome/FF etc but not ie7. How can I get the #toggle-view div to sit on top of the #view img.

Thanks

EDIT: Okay I figured it out. For some reason if the element doesn't have a 'background' property set, it won't handle the z-indexes correctly in ie (any version it seems.. even 9). God I hate IE so much..

Comment: Try to absolute position #view or switch places in the dom so that #toggle-view comes after #view.

Comment: Thanks but I've already tried both of those.. neither worked :-(

Answer (score 1):

When you say on top do you mean you want the div to be on top of it or above it?

I have created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/trickeedickee/wPz2X/ using your code and it works perfectly fine in IE7, you have your #toggle-view div sitting on the right hand side of the container, was this intentional.Let me know if this is the answer and if not I will try help you some more.

Just to be 100% clear I have attached a screengrab of the jsfiddle in IE7. I have the #toggle-view sitting on the left hand side and on top of the image like a layer stack. It is clearly on top of the image. Is this not the outcome you're looking for?

[image]

Comment: Thanks tricked. the div is supposed to sit on top, as in stack on top of the image. It is intentional that it sits on the right too.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a screengrab of my solution, is this not what you are getting in IE7 with the jsfiddle?

Comment: Thanks trickee - that's what I'm after. However getting this to replicate on my site is turning out to be a real problem! I think it may have something to do with the styling of the image.. I'll have another play and see what I can do

Comment: Try giving your image a max-width: 100%; if you want it to fill the entire width of the container.

Comment: In the context of my site, the image only takes up half the screen and sits on the right while the .copy div contains some text. I think I may need to set a width on it though - I'll try just now and report back. I'll mark your response as the answer though as you've clearly got it to work in ie7. Thanks.

Comment: Let me know and I'll try and help out. Cheers.